# Rspec capybara check if substring is in string result

Tags: xpath, rspec, capybara

Ok trying to do a rspec capybara test for a table resultset.

So I have this table

```
**Username   Fullname   Address  Location**  
  simon      Simon Lau   NY        US
  foo.bar    Foo Bar     AU        AU
```

Now i want to get the first row and check if the username (simon) contains the string(mon)

How can i do it dynamically using rspec capybara if we take into consideration that the values might change but I will always want to check the first row and the username column.

Comment: How is this question related to `xpath`?

Comment: how do i find the path of the table? all d way to the specific <td>

Comment: Do you have any HTML you can show?